# How do I sum up a column more efficiently instead of typing it all out one by one?

Tags: python, list

I'm on Lesson 2 of my beginners Python class and I'm trying to understand lists and rows and columns.

I was asked in my assignment to find the average of hr_data which they provided and I was able to solve it, however, I wanted to know if there was a better way to do it. most of the answers on google are for Panda but i haven't learned that yet

I did this :

```
average_rate = (hr_data[0][3] + hr_data[1][3] + hr_data[2][3] + hr_data[3][3])/4


print("The average salary of the employees is :" + str(average_rate))
```

Which got me the correct answer.

But I'm thinking this is easy cos the table was only 4x4 for a basic assignment.  What if in future I deal with a million entries?

Is there a more efficient way to do this?

Also, is there a `len()` formula for columns? I was able to simply divide by 4 since I knew there was only 4 entries , but if I had to work with thousands entries would be a headache suppose?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the aggregate `sum()` in combination with the list notation to access the column values:

```
sum(row[3] for row in hr_data)
```

You can use the `len()` function to get the length of `hr_data`:

```
average_rate = sum(row[3] for row in hr_data) / len(hr_data)
```

For Python 2 you should cast to `float` to avoid integer arithmetic:

```
average_rate = float(sum(row[3] for row in hr_data)) / len(hr_data)
```